# Netty 4.0 EncoderException loss

Tags: netty

I'm using Netty 4.0.32.Final.

When NPE appears in my codec with such a stack trace:

```
my.Codec.encode(Codec.java:27)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$Encoder.encode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:168)
io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107)
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.write(ByteToMessageCodec.java:108)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:908)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:960)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:893)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It vanishes somewhere. So that I couldn't handle it in another Hanler's `exceptionCaught` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an "outbound exception" and so will not show up in exceptionCaught(...). exceptionCaught(...) is only notified for inbound exceptions. The ChannelFuture of the previous write(...) operation will be failed with the exception.